# Does there exist a function $f(x)$, which is “parallel” to $e^x$ and has a finite “norm”?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{\Big(\int_{-M}^{M}(f(x))^2dx\int_{-M}^{M}(e^x)^2dx\Big)^{1/2}}=1
$$
but also the limit
$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-M}^{M} (f(x))^2 dx 
$$
exists and finite?

I suppose the answer is no, but I don’t know how to prove it.

**Motivation.**  I think of the first limit as of some generalization of the cosine between two vectors (as it is somehow similar to a dot product of two vectors divided by their norms). So the first limit says that functions $f(x)$ and $e^x$ are *parallel* in some sense (although not in the common sense as there is a limit before the whole fraction).

The second limit says that that we are looking for a function $f(x)$ with a finite $L_2$-norm (again, not exactly the norm, but maybe its *principal value*).

Functions $f(x) = ae^x$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfy the first condition (as they are *parallel* to $e^x$), but do not satisfy the second (as their “norm” is infinite). I wonder if there exists such $f(x)$ which satisfies both.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out, the answer is **no**, there is no such function.

Without loss of generality we can assume that
$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-M}^{M} (f(x))^2 dx = 2,
$$

which also leads to
$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} f(M)= \lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} f(-M) = 0.
$$

**Suppose** now that there is a function $f$  such that

$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{\Big(\int_{-M}^{M}(f(x))^2dx\int_{-M}^{M}(e^x)^2dx\Big)^{1/2}}=\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{\Big(2\int_{-M}^{M}e^{2x}dx\Big)^{1/2}}=
$$
$$
=\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{\Big(2\cdot \frac{1}{2}(e^{2M}-\underbrace{e^{-2M}}_{\rightarrow 0})\Big)^{1/2}}=\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{e^M}=1.
$$

This limit equals to $1$ as the denominator tends to $+\infty$, which means that the numerator also tends to $+\infty$:

$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx=+\infty.
$$

Now it seems that all the conditions needed to apply L'Hôpital's rule are met, and we can conclude

$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx}{e^M}=1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\Big(\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx\Big)'_M}{\big(e^M\big)'_M} \color{blue}{=1}.
$$

But
$$
\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\Big(\int_{-M}^{M}f(x)e^xdx\Big)'_M}{\big(e^M\big)'_M} = \lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(M)e^M-\overbrace{f(-M)e^{-M}}^{\rightarrow 0}}{e^M} = 
$$
$$
=\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(M)e^M}{e^M}=\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty}f(M) \color{red}{=0},
$$
and we have reached a **contradiction**.

Comment: I'm not sure your first claim is correct: $\int f^2<\infty$ does not imply that $f\to0$. The implication is only true if $\lim_\infty f$ exists in the first place, which is not always the case, right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you, it’s a good point! But it seems to me that everything that comes further works anyway. We only need $f$ to be bounded and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)\ne1$, and both of these follow from $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think $f\in L_2$ implies that $f$ is bounded. Think of thinner and thinner triangles, that become taller as $x\to\infty$, but in such a way that the total area is finite.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, oh, tricky calculus:) So the main mistake is in the end, where I claim $f\in L_2 \Rightarrow \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}f(-M)e^{-M}=0$. I don’t see a good way to fix it.